# "ЭкстрЕмальный" или "экстрИмальный"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: "экстрЕмальный" или "экстрИмальный"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не смотря на то, что "экстрим", нужно писать "экстр***е***мальный". Проверочное слово тут "эстрЕмум".

Answer (score 3):

**Kagami** пишет:

> Не смотря на то, что "экстрим", нужно писать "экстремальный". Проверочное слово тут "эстрЕмум".

**Da Mazai**:

> Екстремумальный? Ecstremum - Lingva Latina - не? Проверять русский язык латинским, енто, как мерять Россию алгеброй.

Замечание по сути верное. Мне кажется, формулировка о *"проверочном слове"* не совсем точна.

На мой взгляд, надо говорить, что слова *"экстрим"* и *"экстремальный"* заимствованы из разных языков. Хотя исходное слово одно и тоже.

Латинское [**extremus**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extremus) [ekˈstreː.mus] - находящийся на краю, на грани, в конце, последний.

Отсюда, из латыни (или через какой-то похожий язык, но всё равно от латыни) и слово *"экстремальный"*.

А слово *"экстрим"* -- это более позднее заимствование, по-видимому из английского.
Англ. [**extreme**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extreme) [ɪkˈstɹiːm] - от старо-французского *extreme*, от латин. *extremus*

Answer (score 1):

Вот хорошая статья на эту тему http://newslab.ru/article/294902

Всё дело в том, что экстрим — вовсе не проверочное слово для перечисленных и прочих однокоренных им слов. Прилагательное «экстремальный» появилось в русском языке куда как раньше этого одиозного существительного, и их орфография практически никак не взаимосвязана. Через французский язык слово «экстремальный» восходит к латинскому extrēmus — «крайний», превосходной степени exterus — «наружный». Отсюда слова экстремум в математике — максимум или минимум функции, экстремизм в политике — приверженность к крайним взглядам и мерам, приставка экстра, означающая выход за пределы чего-либо, высшее качество чего-нибудь.

Экстрим же появился сравнительно недавно, от английского произношения extreme — «крайность», и обычно используется как сокращение выражения «экстремальный спорт» (extreme sports), под которым понимают такой спорт, где люди используют максимум своих возможностей, причём с большой вероятностью серьёзно покалечиться или даже погибнуть. В более общем смысле экстримом называют любую подобную деятельность, которая щекочет нервы. Любителей экстрима, тем не менее, правильнее называть экстремалами, экстремальщиками и не путать с экстремистами. Через и пишем только само слово экстрим и сложные слова, в составе которых оно присутствует: экстрим-гонки, экстрим-пробег.

Answer (score 0):

Екстремумальный?
Ecstremum - Lingva Latina - не?
Проверять русский язык латинским, енто, как мерять Россию алгеброй.